# Create views for one document library and make them available via quick launch

Tags: 2013

I have the following requirement:\

One site collection with one document library, but the library has about 20 metadata columns, and we want to create about 15 views.
The shortcut to the view should appear on the left quick launch menu

How can I do that? via xml view defition is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something that you might be trying to imply in the question but...

You can do it right from the UI, Each view is just an .aspx page, so you can just add a link to the view page to the quick launch.

Here is code from MSDN that you may find useful as well.  You could probably modify this to get the URL of to each view page and then insert it into the quick launch (this could be done from PowerShell as well).

Reference Link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.addtoquicklaunch.aspx

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // Get the Links list or create it if it does not exist.
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Links");

                    if (list == null || list.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.Links)
                    {
                        // Create the list.
                        Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("Links", "Interesting hyperlinks", SPListTemplateType.Links);
                        list = web.Lists.GetList(listId, false);
                    }

                    // Check for an existing link to the list.
                    SPNavigationNode listNode = web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(list.DefaultViewUrl);

                    // No link, so create one.
                    if (listNode == null)
                    {
                        // Create the node.
                        listNode = new SPNavigationNode(list.Title, list.DefaultViewUrl);

                        // Add it to Quick Launch.
                        listNode = web.Navigation.AddToQuickLaunch(listNode, SPQuickLaunchHeading.Lists);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue....");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely something I will do, I am going to provision the views with xml, so after the provisioning I can get the document library and iterate over all views and create the menu easily. thanks a lot